# SonarQube Critical Violation asks for filter on rest api web.xml file

Tags: sonarqube, resteasy, code-injection, servlet-filters

The SonarQube hint (rule "[Web applications should use validation filters](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3355)") suggests this compliant solution:

```
public class ValidatingHttpRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
  // ...
}

public class ValidationFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    chain.doFilter(new ValidatingHttpRequest( (HttpServletRequest)request ), response);
  }
}
```

and in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ValidationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.myco.servlet.ValidationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ValidationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But I have no clue of what validations are expected here. My code is a rest api (resteasy implementation) and all services are under `"/rest/*` path. Is this a false positive case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OWASP, injection flaws are one of the top application security risks ([link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2017-A1-Injection)). The basic prevention idea includes automatic validation of all input values using the [whitelist](https://update-wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Positive_security_model) approach. In order to implement it in Java EE, OWASP suggests using a custom filter, you can find more details with some restrictive patterns [here](https://update-wiki.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_validation_logic_to_HttpServletRequest).

tl;dr: Sonar requires you to filter out some potentially unsafe input characters.

In my opinion, this rule is too general and does not apply to all of the possible applications - it is possible to prevent code injection in many ways.

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer for the good link reference. Thanks